# How to add custom document in nextJs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to create a custom document for my new nextjs 13 project and use custom design system package. The package requires custom documents in the page directory as the nextjs official [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-document#:%7E:text=Custom%20Document-,Custom%20Document,-A%20custom) guided. However, there is no documents for custom document in app directory structure in nextjs 13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `app/layout.tsx` (which is called root layout) if you are using `app` router.

The root layout replaces the `_app.js` and `_document.js` files from `pages` router.

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

> The root layout is defined at the top level of the app directory and applies to all routes. This layout enables you to modify the initial HTML returned from the server.
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required

If you are not using TypeScript, you can use the name: `app/layout.js`.